# Block quotes not shown correctly in PDF export of resume

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, pdf

This is how it looks on the web

[image: Web version of block quotes]

This is how it looks in the PDF export

[image: pdf version of block quotes]

It would nice if the the styling matched

Answer (score 2):

This is done; simple css change.